# clover / bullshtml - How to show source code lines

Tags: clover, bullseye

At the moment, the detailed breakdown shows the function calls but doesn't provide a breakdown of source code lines as you do if you use covhtml to generate the report.  Is it because it's looking for the source in the place specified by the covfile and the time bullshtml is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The original location of the sources is not found, so it does not show the lines of code. You can overcome this problem by using `CoverageBrowser`, which comes among the other Bullseye tools (inside the Bullseye `bin` directory).

When you run `CoverageBrowser`, browse to a source you'd like to examine. Double click it. Then you will see:

[image]

Press the `locate` button. Locate the file (in a file tree structure which is identical to the one you generated the cov file from). The `CoverageBrowser` will then show all the files in the tree with lines of code/